# Store Model as JSON in Hidden input and access it in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

How do I store a Model in a hidden input and access it in my javascript function?

I am storing the model in a hidden field as

```
string defaultFareListJson = 
      Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(@Model.DefaultFare);
@Html.Hidden("DefaultFareList", defaultFareListJson);
```

And in my Javascript function, I am trying to access it as:

```
function viewDefaultFareSchedule() {
        var defaultFareObject = {}        
        defaultFareObject.Fares = jQuery.parseJSON($('#DefaultFareList').val());
        alert(defaultFareObject.Fares[0].facility);            
    }
```

My ViewModel is as follows:

```
public class NavBarCallerViewModel
    {        
        public FareSchedViewModel DefaultFare { get; set; } = new FareSchedViewModel();
    }

public class FareSchedViewModel {
        public string facility{get;set;}
}
```

NH

Comment: Have you tried storing a model in a hidden input field to access it with JavaScript? Have you tried any code that you can share with us?

Comment: So far, this is what I am doing:

Comment: store the view model in a hidden filed like                                                              string defaultFareListJson = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(@Model.DefaultFare);
@Html.Hidden("DefaultFareList", defaultFareListJson);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to parse a hidden JSON string("DefaultFareList": converted from Model) as :

```
var defaultFareString = document.getElementById('DefaultFareList').value;
var defaultFare = JSON.parse(defaultFareString);
```